# Why does loading a driver through pytest result in a SIGABRT?

Tags: python, driver, pytest, python-import

I'm using pytest to drive some integration tests, some of which require a simulator, so I've created a pytest fixture that initialises it.

The simulator uses a driver that's provided within another Python module, which I import in **conftest.py** like so:

```
from foo.bar.sim import Sim
```

The `Sim` then imports the driver:

```
from pc_ble_driver_py import ble_driver as ble_driver
```

And within `ble_driver`, the underlying module is eventually loaded:

```
_mod = imp.load_module('_pc_ble_driver_sd_api_v3', fp, pathname, description)
```

As far as I can see from debugging, `load_module` is getting all it needs to load the driver properly. And, in fact, if I run the simulator away from pytest, everything's just peachy. But, when I try to load the simulator by executing `pytest` – when I want to use the simulator in my tests – the `load_module` call results in a pretty catastrophic failure:

```
[1]    12126 abort      pytest tests/test_integration.py
```

What the fudge is going on? Why can't the driver be loaded by or on behalf of pytest?

**UPDATE:**

As recommended, I have tried running the test through `gdb`, which in itself was a bit of a mission. Please see below for the stack trace at the point of the crash. I'm not sure how helpful this is, as I'm not sure I've been able to properly use a debug version of Python:

```
Thread 2 received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fff6515e49a in ?? ()
```

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff6515e49a in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fff6521b6cb in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: `pytest` doesn't send `SIGABRT`s. Run the tests from gdb and see what the error trace reports.

Comment: I've tried running the test through `gdb` as recommended. Please see the update.